# <button> that changes "navigation titles" with "content field" / passing data from child to parent

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router

Learning **React** by rebuilding a simple page I made:

[supg.info](https://supg.info)

I got stuck, trying to recreate "main navigation" functionality - chevron `<button>`, that changes both "navigation titles" with "content field" of `<main>` - represented in my app by `<Dod />` and `<Analogia />` components. I managed to write a *useNextTitle* `hook`, that "on click" of the button changes titles, but with that, "content fields" would have to change also - not sure how to do this.

The way I'm thinking, data from that `hook` that is being returned to `<Nav />` would be useful if I could pass it to parent `App.js` , so I could write a function that alters `display` of "component wrapping" `<section>`s (by changing their `.class`),  or somehow set up a `Router`. Was reading about `useContext` hook also.

App.js

```
import Nav from "./components/Nav";

function App() {

  return (

    <div className="App">

      <Nav />
      
      <main>
        <section  className="menu-title__cont">
          <Dod/>
        </section>
        <section className="menu-title__cont">
          <Analogia/>
        </section>
      </main>

    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Nav.js

```
import useNextTitle from './useNextTitle';

const Nav = () => {

    const { navData, val, nextTitle} = useNextTitle();

    return (
        <nav>

            {/* titles */}
            <ul className="nav-up--main">
                <li key="li1" className="um">
                    {navData.map((title, index) => {
                        return (
                            <div 
                                className={index === val ? "active" : "display-none"} key={title.id}>
                                {title.text}
                            </div>
                        )
                    })}
                </li>
            </ul>

            {/* chevron */}
                <button onClick={nextTitle}>
                    <span className="material-icons">
                        chevron_right
                    </span>
                </button>       
        </nav>
  )
}
export default Nav
```

useNextTitle

```
import { useState } from 'react';

const useNextTitle = () => {

    const navData = [
        {id: 0, text: "DOD Wear"},
        {id: 1, text: "analogia"}
    ]

    const [val, setVal] = useState(0);

    const nextTitle = () => {
        setVal(val === navData.length -1 ? 0 : val + 1 )
        console.log(val)

    }
    return { navData, val, nextTitle }
}

export default useNextTitle;
```

Comment: It's unclear what any issue is, or what you are asking for. Are you asking how to [lift state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) so the title state resides in `App` so it can be passed down to children?

Comment: trying to recreate "blue navigation", like here: [supg.info](http://supg.info). Dont know how to make "main pages" change - with the "titles" in navigation.

Comment: If I could raise the state up from <Nav/> to App.js, mainly the `val` const, that changes after click, I could use this to write a function that controls the `<Dod/>` and `<Analogia/>` components, which are the App.js children.

Comment: That is the general idea, yes. Do you need help with this?

Comment: that would be amazing sir. My explanation may be vague, after giving it more time , i've rephrased it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71528902/passing-value-from-child-to-parent-after-click-event-in-child-which-triggers-f)