# Passing value from child to parent, after click event in child (which triggers function)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

In `<Nav/>` component, "click event" on chevron `<button>`, triggers `nextTitle(length)` function in *useNextTitle.js* custom hook. This function sets the value of `val`, which is being returned by *useNextTitle.js*. How to pass that new `val` to *App.js* ?

---

Bigger picture: I want to change the display between `<Dod />` and `<Analogia />` (in App.js), after "click event" in `<Nav />` (figured out `val` would be helpful for that, as a parameter in Conditional Statement).

Functionality I`m trying to achieve is visualized on the website I done with vanilla *Java Script* : [link](https://supg.info) (the blue navigation, changes "main pages" with "titles" when chevron clicked)

**App.js**

```
import Nav from "./components/Nav";
import Dod from "./components/Dod";
import Analogia from "./components/Analogia";

function App() {

  return (

   <div className="App">

     <Nav />

     <Dod />

     <Analogia />


   </div>
     );
}

export default App
```

**Nav.js**

```
import useNextTitle from './useNextTitle';
import './Nav.css';

const Nav = () => {

  const navData = [
    {id: 0, text: "DOD"},
    {id: 1, text: "analogia"}
  ]

  const length = navData.length;

  const { val, nextTitle } = useNextTitle();

  return (
    <nav>
    <div>


        {/* titles */}
        <ul>
            <li key="li1">
                {navData.map((title, index) => {
                    return (
                        <div 
                            className={index === val ? "active" : "display-none"} key={title.id}>
                            {title.text}
                        </div>
                    )
                })}
            </li>
        </ul>

        {/* chevron button */}
        <div>
            <button onClick={() => nextTitle(length)}>
                <span className="material-icons">
                    chevron_right
                </span>
            </button>
        </div>
        
    </div>
    </nav>
  )
}
export default Nav
```

**useNextTitle.js**

```
import { useState } from 'react';

const useNextTitle = () => {

    const [val, setVal] = useState(0);

    const nextTitle = (length) => {
        setVal(val === length -1 ? 0 : val + 1 )
        console.log("hook vav = " + val)
    }
    return { val, nextTitle }
}

export default useNextTitle;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the `useNextTitle` hook/state up to `App` and pass `val` and `nextTitle` down to `Nav` to toggle/update the state. Use `val` to conditionally render `Dod` and `Analogia`.

Example:

```
function App() {
  const { val, nextTitle } = useNextTitle();
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Nav {...{ val, nextTitle }} />
      {val === 0 && <Dod />}
      {val === 1 && <Analogia />}
    </div>
  );
}
```

...

```
const Nav = ({ val, nextTitle }) => {
  const navData = [
    { id: 0, text: "DOD" },
    { id: 1, text: "analogia" }
  ];

  const length = navData.length;

  return (
    <nav>
      <div>
        {/* titles */}
        <ul>
          <li key="li1">
            {navData.map((title, index) => {
              return (
                <div
                  className={index === val ? "active" : "display-none"}
                  key={title.id}
                >
                  {title.text}
                </div>
              );
            })}
          </li>
        </ul>

        {/* chevron button */}
        <div>
          <button onClick={() => nextTitle(length)}>
            <span className="material-icons">chevron_right</span>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit passing-value-from-child-to-parent-after-click-event-in-child-which-triggers-f]

Comment: Thank you Sir. I think I understand the concept of lifting the state up now, need a minute  to figure out the pipeline. Your answer was very helpful!

Comment: @bartc Welcome, glad to help. Cheers and good luck!

Comment: If I could ask one more thing. In _App.js_ I haven't came across the `...` syntax, when passing props in `<Nav />`.  This is the syntax specifically for passing custom hook values?

Comment: @bartc No, I was just lazy when throwing together the sandbox and didn't feel like typing out `val={val} nextTitle={nextTitle}` when I could just type `{ ... }` and copy/paste in the `{ val, nextTitle }` I'd destructured from the hook. `...` is the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) and comes in handy when you've a "props" object and want to pass the *entire* object's properties in as individual props to a component.